# Hapi Front End different server

Tags: node.js, hapi

I am trying to build a HAPI REST (API) Server. I think I'd like to make a separate NodeJS server for the front end and separate the two entirely. It would be nice that they don't know about each other at all to simplify development (like both having access to the database - but I assume that would allow for collisions and crazy things).

The idea is so I can scale one and not the other, or I can secure them differently (user/pass for front end, api key for back end), or replace one and not the other.

I assume I should have two different servers, how do I do this? I have seen people just make "two instances" listening on different ports, but it is the same code and can't actually be on separate server instances?

Perhaps I am thinking about this wrong. I assume this MUST be common, what is the regular approach?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track. Have you read [this part of the documentation](https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/docs/server_plain/get_started.html)?

There's a [github repo](https://github.com/FirelyTeam/fhirstarters/tree/master/java/hapi-fhirstarters-simple-server/) that suggests a starting point.

One strategy might be to embed a Jetty server at a custom context path in your Java app and respond to Hapi Fhir queries.

You should be able to then proxy all your requests at the server level for secure things like user auth or open up certain resources to be queried openly from NodeJS or any REST api.

Finding out how to embed a jetty server should be simple. Proxying requests and auth, maybe not so much